# How do I place my ImageButton infront of my TextView with elevation?

Tags: android, xml, textview, imagebutton

I'm adding a dialog box to my app and I want to place my exit/close ImageButton over my TextView which has a custom background with rounded corners and white background, but the ImageButton keeps staying behind the TextView.

[After Building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXEIN.png)
[In Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnUS7.png)

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tCarparkName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Parkhausname"      
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibClose"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/a"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain visually? what you want to achieve

Comment: Check my uploaded Images for better understanding.

Comment: provide your full layout file too...

Comment: I added my layout thanks!

Comment: Is first image your expected output?

Comment: Use a Relative layout then first add textView and after that add ImageView inside Relative layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting `elevation` on your `TextView`. try to set `translationZ` or `elevation`on your ImageButton too :

`android:translationZ="5dp"` or   `android:elevation="5dp"`

Comment: That easy! Thank you.

Comment: Accept it as answer if it helped you, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

android:elevation="5dp"

That makes the elevation for your layout